# Schema version issue in Icinga 2

Tags: mysql, debian, icinga

I'm installing icinga2 on Debian from:

```
deb http://debmon.org/debmon debmon-jessie main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

As described here:
http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/getting-started#setting-up-mysql-db

I run:

```
apt-get install icinga2-ido-mysql
apt-get install icingaweb2
```

and it perform self-configuration.
Now, I'm accessing http://localhost/icingaweb2/setup
and on DB configure page it gives me:

> The database you've configured to use for Icinga Web 2 seems to be the one >of Icinga. Please be aware that this database configuration is supposed to >be used for Icinga Web 2's configuration and that it is highly recommended >to not mix different schemas in the same database. If this is intentional, >you can skip the validation and ignore this warning. If not, please provide >a different database.

I run DB configuration manually with:

```
mysql -u root -p icinga < /usr/share/icinga2-ido-mysql/schema/mysql.sql
```

as manual requires, and gives new DB name, and get same error...
In GitHub, in the project's section, in DbResourcePage.php on line 133 the error yields.
Can some one suggest me what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update the icingaweb2 schema:

```
mysql -u root -p icinga < /usr/share/icinga2-ido-mysql/schema/icinga_web.sql
```

Hoping this helps you in.

Cheers

Comment: I already installed old version of the service, and can not test the suggestion, but I will put your answer as correct hoping that it will help other ) thank you for your answer.